# get the name of the object calling one of its methods

Tags: php, oop

is it possible to get the name of the object which calls one of its methods.

scenario:

I have class A. I instantiate 2 objects of that class. If one object calls a method, is it possible to retrieve the name of the object which called it?

EDIT:

```
class Property() {
   public function __call($name, $atts) {
      if ($name === 'foo') {
         //I want to differ Between Color and Position
      }
   }
}

$Color = new Property();
$Position = new Property();

$Color->foo();
$Position->foo();
```

Comment: what do you expect the name of the object to be?

Answer (score 2):

Add a name element to your object:

```
class ObJA {
    $this->name;
    function __construct($name){
         $this->name = $name;
    }

    function getName(){ return $this->name;  }
}
```

On object create:

```
$a = new ObJA('a');
$b = new ObJA('is b');

echo $a->getName(); //`a`
echo $b->getName(); //`is b`
```

Comment: I also had this idea but I thought there might be another way which I just haven't found out, yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php), but the name is not going to change simply by creating two or more instances of the object. [Neal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375738/get-the-name-of-the-object-calling-one-of-its-methods/6375763#6375763) will work but it doesn't actually change the name of the class, and begs the question: Why do you need it?